# Solving equation with rescaled coordinates

Tags: perturbation-theory

Working through [Murdock's Pertubations](https://books.google.com/books?id=C_I-aqj6Lc4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) [1.5.5 and] 1.6.3 here...

We're working to solve $x^3 - 2x^2 + x - \epsilon^2 = 0$.

When trying with rescaled coordinates, I'm having trouble choosing coordinates that don't have multiple roots. I tried $y=x/\epsilon$ and $y=x-1$, but I'm still stuck with double roots. What should I be trying instead?

Comment: Maybe $y=\frac{x-1}{\epsilon}$?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to sketch the unperturbed situation, i.e. the graph of $x^3 -2 x^2 +x$. The roots of $x^3 - 2x^2 +x$ are the intersections of the graph with the horizontal axis. 
When $\epsilon > 0$, this graph is shifted slightly downwards. As you can see, the root at $x=0$ shifts slightly to the right, whereas the double root at $x=1$ splits into two roots, both close to and on either side of $x=1$.

For the root near the origin, you tried $x = \epsilon y$. When you substitute that in the equation and expand in $\epsilon$, the leading order term implies $y=0$ -- but then you're back where you started, since you already knew that the root you're looking for is near $x=0$. To determine what goes wrong here, I suggest you study example 1.5.2 in Murdock.

For the two roots near the double root at $x=1$, you tried $x = 1+y$. When you substitute that in the equation and expand in $\epsilon$, the leading order term again implies $y=0$, so again, you're back where you started. Again, something goes wrong, but now for a different reason! To determine what goes wrong here, I suggest you study example 1.5.3 in Murdock.

Comment: 1.5.2 and 1.5.3 are about solving it with undetermined gauges, not rescaled coordinates. What should I be seeing in them?

Comment: Undetermined gauges are an extension of rescaled coordinates: you rescale your coordinates with a function of $\epsilon$, instead of just $\epsilon$ itself. In this case, the treatment of both examples should clarify what you should do in your case. I suggest you work through both of them, that should give you enough insight to tackle your original problem. Good luck!

Comment: I'm still having trouble, unfortunately. Can you provide any more of a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Sure, can you explain what you tried, and where you're having trouble exactly? Maybe by updating your question with your attempt? Then I can edit my answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate perhaps on the relationship between undetermined gauges and rescaled coordinates that you alluded to? I've looked through the examples you suggested and don't see how that indicates to me what rescaling to use.

Comment: The idea is to use the method outlined in the examples to find yourself what rescaling to use. The problems in the examples are different, so the resulting rescaling will generally be different; the method to arrive at the proper rescaling is the same though. Really, the key is to sit down with pen and paper and work these things through in detail: just skimming the treatment for answers won't get you very far.